# How can I add parameters with unwrapped name of struct SoapHeader in C#

Tags: c#, soap, header

If I use object SoapHeader a have I a struct with name of SoapHeader (xml element MySoapHeaderName):

```
<Envelope> 
  <Header>
 <MySoapHeaderName>
  <param1>111</param1>
  <param2>222</param2>
 </MySoapHeaderName>
</Header>
<Body>
   .....SomeBody.....
</Body>
```

And I want to remove tags MySoapHeaderName

```
<Envelope> 
 <Header>
  <param1>111</param1>
  <param2>222</param2>
 </Header>
 <Body>
   .....SomeBody.....
 </Body>
</Envelope>
```

How Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use **XmlTextAttribute** for param in soapheader. I added so many soapheaders classes as i need and the result is what i'm waiting for:

```
public class param1 : SoapHeader
{
 [XmlTextAttribute()]
 public string MyParam1;
}
public class param2 : SoapHeader
{
 [XmlTextAttribute()]
 public string MyParam2;
}
```

And set property to the method:

```
[SoapHeader("param1",Direction=SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]
[SoapHeader("param2",Direction=SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)] 
public someresult MyMethod
```

Header is:

```
<Header>
 <param1>111</param1>
 <param2>222</param2>
</Header>
```